# PHP - Laravel - Trait method token has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a *passwordless* login flow to my existing Laravel application, which **also** have Laravel Passport implemented.

I have created a new trait `MagicallyAuthenticatable`, to extend the `User.php` class:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Auth\Traits\MagicallyAuthenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, MagicallyAuthenticatable;
    [ ... ]
}
```

My trait is like below:

```
namespace App\Auth\Traits;

trait MagicallyAuthenticatable
{
    public function storeToken()
    {
        $this->token()->delete();
        $this->token()->create([
            'token' => str_random(255)
        ]);

        return $this;
    }

    public function token()
    {
        return 'token'; //just for test
    }
}
```

When I try to login, I get this error though:

> Trait method token has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User

Comment: It sees there are other methods named "token" or "storeToken" included by some other trait. Could you try remove your trait, and call one of those methods on a user to see if they exist, and where they come from ?

Comment: Most likely these methods already exist in the 
`HasApiTokens`. You can name your methods differently or remove this trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `HasApiToken` from the `passport` package already uses a method `token()`.

```
    /**
     * Get the current access token being used by the user.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Passport\Token|null
     */
    public function token()
    {
        return $this->accessToken;
    }
```

According to PHP docs,

> If two Traits insert a method with the same name, a fatal error is
>   produced, if the conflict is not explicitly resolved.
>
> To resolve naming conflicts between Traits used in the same class, the
>   insteadof operator needs to be used to choose exactly one of the
>   conflicting methods.
>
> Since this only allows one to exclude methods, the as operator can be
>   used to add an alias to one of the methods. Note the as operator does
>   not rename the method and it does not affect any other method either.

**Conflict resolution**

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!! I just changed the name in my trait to something other than `token` :)